# Removing multiple files in the R program environment

Tags: r

I am new to R program.

I have a lot of files in the environment, x1,x2,x3.....x1279.

How do I remove all the x files?

I used to use GrADs, where I can simply remove the files using asterik *

Is there a similar function in R? Do I have to use a while loop?

eg.

```
n<-1
while(n<1279){

remove(x*,n)

n<-n+1

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: No need for `grep` - `rm(list = ls(pattern="^x"))`

Comment: work like a charm. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything from the environment using rm(list=ls()). See `?rm` and `?ls`.

Comment: Hi, I dont wanna remove all. only the x files. there are also other files in the environment as well.